# Input image preparation in Caffe

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, io, profiling, caffe

Before feeding input image into the network, Caffe reads the input image from disk and transforms them (crop, mirror, ...). It seems that large portion of batch processing time is spent on this data preparation and I am trying to figure out which step of data preparation takes longer.

For the input image, I generated lmdb file from ilsvrc12 using the script (example/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh) and the generated file size is about 200kb per image.

In data layer, when loading batch, Caffe reports prefetch time including read time and transformation time. (load_batch() in src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp)

When I run bvlc_alexnet with batch size 256, Caffe reports as below:

```
I0331 10:09:47.987857 10968 data_layer.cpp:137] Prefetch batch: 427 ms.
I0331 10:09:47.987918 10968 data_layer.cpp:138]      Read time: 116.003 ms.
I0331 10:09:47.987934 10968 data_layer.cpp:139] Transform time: 308.26ms.
```

1) From this result, data transfer rate can be calculated like: 200kb*256/116.003ms = 441mb/s. However, since I am using HDD not SSD, this is way over the limit of HDD bandwidth (expected bandwidth is about 150mb/s). I also flushed memory cache to make sure that all data is loaded from the disk.

Is it correct that "Read time" in the report indicates loading time from HDD to memory? I doubt that the "Read time" and "Transform time" is the actual read/transform time since the data in the disk may be loaded to main memory **on demand** so "Read time" becomes shorter and "Transform Time" becomes longer than the actual time spent. How can measure the actual data load and transform time?

2) One way to measure actual data load time I tried was eliminating transform overhead by transforming the input data in advance. But I cannot find the way to do so. Is there any way to preprocess the transform and load already transformed data instead of raw data?